# How can i upload a Spring Java project to GitHub so i can show my work?

Tags: spring, github

I've tried through various ways, directly uploading the files wont work. I've tried through bash and nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have git installed?

```
# Create a new repository on the command line

#Go to Project Directory on your Computer, Open git Bash here

# run the following 1 by 1 

git init

git add .

git commit -m "Comment here"

git remote add origin https://github.com/YourRepoPrefixHere

git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Make sure you downloaded git from here 
https://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a git profile and a repository you can take these simple steps to get it online:

1. Open a terminal and go inside the folder of the project you want to push to your git repository
2. Check if you are on the right git branch: **git checkout**
3. **git add .**
4. **git commit -m "your messagge to commit"**
5. **git push origin -u "yourbranchName**

If you have never set up your origin branch, you should add it before using it:

**git remote add origin "github link"**

To see if everything went well you can do a simple: **git status**.

I hope it will be useful to you my friend!